# Copy Firefox Profile - what is needed for the Root CA

Tags: firefox, root-certificate

for parallel test execution, I need multiple Firefox profiles. Every instance of Firefox needs to import a custom Root CA. So I thought i just create a profile, import the CA and then copy the profile, which works fine.

But does somebody know what the minimal required files are? I dont want to copy the bookmarks or anything like that, the Root CA is the only critical thing.
Files in the profile:

```
bookmarkbackups
safebrowsing
startupCache
webapps
.parentlock
cert8.db
compatibility.ini
content-prefs.sqlite
cookies.sqlite
downloads.sqlite
extensions.ini
extensions.sqlite
formhistory.sqlite
key3.db
localstore.rdf
mimeTypes.rdf
permissions.sqlite
places.sqlite
pluginreg.dat
prefs.js
search.json
secmod.db
signons.sqlite
webappsstore.sqlite
```

Files needed for imported Root CA:

```
?
```

If anybody just knows this, it would save a lot of time. Else I will just trial and error a solution :)

Regards
Wormi

Comment: […seeing a file called "cert8.db" in the list ought to have been enough of a clue. That's why I downvoted your question…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765333/copy-firefox-profile-what-is-needed-for-the-root-ca/22765478#comment34705856_22765478) – wrote the person who needed a Google search to find his answer. Tsss! To show that not everyone at StackOverflow is that hypocritical, you’ve got my upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data), via a Google search for "firefox profile certificate database":

> Security certificate settings: The cert8.db file stores all your security certificate settings and any SSL certificates you have imported into Firefox.

Comment: oh, well that was easy...
i did include the key3.db which lead to strange errors, so i thought it might be more complicated.
thanks a lot

Comment: Yup! Not but what seeing a file called "cert8.db" in the list ought to have been enough of a clue. That's why I downvoted your question; next time, put some thought into the problem *before* you post.

Comment: I meant I included both cert8.db and key3.db and got an error. But i guess the downvote is still valid

Comment: It would've been worth mentioning in the question that you tried that, and including the text of the error message. (For one thing, it'd have saved you a downvote.)